# Any stories about Zombies in the desert

Tags: zombie

I have seen stories which cover frozen zombies, or ones that can go through the ocean. I don't think I have ever read a story that deals with Zombies in a desert environment. Potentially this would be a good escape route as they would dehydrate and not be able to move.

Has this been covered by anyone?

Comment: From Dusk Till Dawn?

Comment: [Road Wars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvlVDXXBOzE): the real Mad Max 4.

Comment: There are bits and pieces of stories about zombies in desert environments in the book *World War Z*, and a few stories about desert zombies in the *Recorded Attacks* appendix to *The Zombie Survival Guide*, both of which were written by Max Brooks.  The graphic novel adaptation of *Recorded Attacks* has illustrated versions of most of those related stories.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There's a 2013 film named [*The Desert*](http://rantbit.com/2015/03/22/the-desert-aka-zombie-desert-aka-whats-left-of-us-2013/) and there's a webcomic named [Zombie Ranch](http://www.zombieranchcomic.com/) that's at least set in a very arid area if not the desert itself. I don't think either really address desiccation of the zombies.

Answer (score 2):

[Resident Evil: Extinction](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0432021/) takes place in a dusty old desert, doesn't seem to affect the zombies much though